# How can I make my Bot to send a random predefined embed message?

Tags: discord.py

Whenever I run the command, it responds the text literrally, not embedded. Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def item(ctx):
    items = [
    'embed = discord.Embed(title = "embed1", description = "test1")', 
    'embed = discord.Embed(title = "embed2", description = "test2")']
    randomitem = random.choice(items)
    await ctx.send (randomitem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
@client.command()
async def item(ctx):
    items = [
    discord.Embed(title = "embed1", description = "test1"), 
    discord.Embed(title = "embed2", description = "test2")]
    randomitem = random.choice(items)
    await ctx.send(embed=randomitem) # embed= - for send discord.Embed
```

Answer (score 0):

the `items` list is filled with strings, not actual embed objects.
so to get the result you want you need to remove the quotations around the embed objects like so:

```
items = [ embed = discord.Embed(title = "embed1", description = "test1"), 
          embed = discord.Embed(title = "embed2", description = "test2")]
```

because of the quotations Python just sees them as strings.

A better way of writing your code would be

```
items = [discord.Embed(title = "embed1", description = "test1"),
         discord.Embed(title = "embed2", description = "test2")]
return ctx.send(embed=random.choice(items))
```